# Reset Default Manuscript Style Set

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

I changed some of the settings in the Manuscript Style Set, but would like to reset them back to the default. I realized too late that what I should be doing is creating a new Style Set. I've searched and keep finding answers on how to reset the normal.doc defaults, but not how to reset a Style Set. How do I do this? Or, at least, what are the settings so I can do it manually?

Comment: `Home tab / Styles / Change Styles / Style Set` has [two options](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bT4AM.jpg) titled *Reset to Quick Styles from Template* and *Reset Document Quick Styles*. Have you tried them?